# How to avoid route overlaping?

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I’m having a problem with a route that is overlaping others. The route is this:

```
Route::get('{category}/{year?}/{month?}/{day?}/{slug?}’, [ArticleCategoryController::class, 'getArticlesByCategory'])
    ->name('category.articles’);
```

And I can’t access, for example, domain.com/login cause the app takes "login" as a category. Any advice?

**UPDATE 1**: The route is at the end.
[image: Routes]

**UPDATE 2**: At my local computer, using Valet, is working as expected. But I uploaded to two different servers and in both is failing.

Answer (score 0):

You just put it at the bottom of your web or API file